# How do bind the FontFamily of a label to a dynamic resource in C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's the code I have:

```
        var LL = new Label()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        };
        LL.SetDynamicResource(FontFamilyProperty, "Default-Medium");
```

I was trying to do it with the last line but it gives an error saying FontFamilyProperty does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
var LL = new Label()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            };
            LL.SetDynamicResource(Label.FontFamilyProperty, "Default-Medium");
```

If you want to learn more than information for dynamic resources, you can look this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic)